# Android app crashes after SDK-tools update version (NoClassDefFound, tool version 22)

Tags: java, android, sdk, crash

I have just updated my android SDK tools to the newly released version (tools version 22, platform tools version 17)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

The .classpath file was modified. The update in added a line :

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
```

Before the SDK tools update, all my projects worked well !!

**I corrected my problem in this way :**

- In the project properties (eclipse) -> java build path -> order and export make sure that all your jars in the libs folder are checked.
- And "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties"
- And "Project -> Clean"

But I don't understand why! Would anybody have an explanation ?

Comment: are you using any support library

Comment: answer your own question with the solution, you helped me fixing the annoying problem

Comment: Samle problem!! Even my files are generated by AndroidAnnotations. It seems like they are not added to the build path.

Comment: Do not forget to do a "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties" then "Project -> Clean".

Comment: @lopez.mikhael didnt fix the issue. What did you check in the Oder and Export tab?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, exact same error. I've tried what @lopez.mikhael suggested and it didn't resolve my problem.

I asked my question on the androiddev subreddit....http://redd.it/1egrgr

Comment: +1. It works for me. I have tried many other solutions this morning.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I fixed it by going into Java Build Path > Order and Export tab.

Click <del>everything in the list</del> "Android Private Libraries".

Then "Project -> Clean". That fixed my issue.

Just over 1.5 days on this issue, solved my problem by reading [Google+](https://plus.google.com/110261362522479570091/posts/4a55Afj2DrM).

Comment: I've just checked it carefully and we only need to check the new dependency "Android Private Libraries" (not all) and then do the "Project > Clean". Thanks @acedanger.

Comment: You're welcome:-) ("Fix Project Properties" isn't needed either!)

Comment: Awesome! Was struggling with this for a while... Why android, why?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue as StylezSoft. To clarify even further, below is my Java Build Path from Eclipse after that I solved the issue (by ticking the `android-support-v4.jar` library)

[image]

Then I cleaned the Project (Project > Clean... > OK) and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after the upgrade. The problem in my case was that the android-support-v4.jar library had become unchecked in the Order and Export- list. Check + rebuild solved it for me.

The error manifested itself by crashing the app when opening a dialog with a Facebook LoginButton widget on it.

Answer (score 0):

Also need to make sure the Android Dependencies is checked in the Order & Export tab. Both are needed when using other library projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, following two steps fixed it:-

1. Java Build Path -> Order and Export tab.
2. Then "Project -> Clean".

Answer (score 0):

I solve this with Android Tools->Add support Library

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. But the problem was jar mismatch of "android-support-v4.jar" between Facebook SDK and my application. When I copied the same jar file from Facebook SDK to my application lib folder, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on Android Studio. Since most of the answers here are for Eclipse, here's how to add the supportv4 library on Android Studio:

1. Build -> Edit Libraries and Dependencies
2. Click the + button
3. Select the support-v4 library
4. Click OK.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Check Exports Order
2. Enable Multi Dex
3. Check api level of views in layout. I faced same problem with searchView. I have check api level while adding searchview but added implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener to class file.
4. Check support Libraries v4,v7 etc

Comment: This is the mvp answer, multi dex fixed it for us