# android project giving error "unfortunately the app has stopped"

Tags: android

i am able to compile, build and install the project successfully. But can not get it to run. Every time it is launched, it says "unfortunately the app has stopped". here is all i could get into logcat. But I could not understand this. Could you please help me figure this out

```
07-11 23:40:03.555: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity; (128    )
07-11 23:40:03.605: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:03.605: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/InviteFriendsActivity; (678)
07-11 23:40:03.605: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/InviteFriendsActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:03.605: E/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find class 'com.example.healthcity.activities.InviteFriendsActivity', referenced from method com.example.healthcity.common.Prefs.moveToNewActivity
07-11 23:40:03.605: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 580 (Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/InviteFriendsActivity;) in Lcom/example/healthcity/common/Prefs;
07-11 23:40:03.605: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x008a
07-11 23:40:03.635: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity; (128)
07-11 23:40:03.635: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:03.635: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity; (678)
07-11 23:40:03.650: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:03.650: E/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find class 'com.example.healthcity.activities.GroupLessonsActivity', referenced from method com.example.healthcity.common.Prefs.moveToNewActivity
07-11 23:40:03.650: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 560 (Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;) in Lcom/example/healthcity/common/Prefs;
07-11 23:40:03.650: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x00d9
07-11 23:40:03.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity; (128)
07-11 23:40:03.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:03.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/ContactActivity; (678)
07-11 23:40:03.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/ContactActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:03.826: E/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find class 'com.example.healthcity.activities.ContactActivity', referenced from method com.example.healthcity.common.Prefs.moveToNewActivity
07-11 23:40:03.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 548 (Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/ContactActivity;) in Lcom/example/healthcity/common/Prefs;
07-11 23:40:03.826: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0129
07-11 23:40:03.896: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsSpecialSocialDialogActivity; (128)
07-11 23:40:03.905: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsSpecialSocialDialogActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:03.925: E/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find class 'com.example.healthcity.activities.GroupLessonsSpecialSocialDialogActivity', referenced from method com.example.healthcity.common.Prefs.moveToNewActivity
07-11 23:40:03.925: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 566 (Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsSpecialSocialDialogActivity;) in Lcom/example/healthcity/common/Prefs;
07-11 23:40:03.936: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0199
07-11 23:40:03.955: I/System.out(1760): ###################################################################
07-11 23:40:03.955: I/System.out(1760): ##################  HealthCity App Born 0.3.6 debug:false (Basic Fit)
07-11 23:40:03.955: I/System.out(1760): ###################################################################
07-11 23:40:03.965: I/System.out(1760): ------------------PRODUCT: 1 DEBUG:false BASICFIT
07-11 23:40:04.055: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity; (128)
07-11 23:40:04.055: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.055: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity; (678)
07-11 23:40:04.055: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.055: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3892 (clubId) in Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;
07-11 23:40:04.055: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x005b
07-11 23:40:04.075: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity; (128)
07-11 23:40:04.075: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.075: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity; (678)
07-11 23:40:04.075: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.087: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3916 (me) in Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;
07-11 23:40:04.087: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x002b
07-11 23:40:04.095: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity; (128)
07-11 23:40:04.095: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.095: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity; (678)
07-11 23:40:04.095: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.105: I/dalvikvm(1760): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0f37 at 0x5d in Lcom/example/healthcity/networking/Networking;.doInBackground
07-11 23:40:04.105: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity; (128)
07-11 23:40:04.105: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/common/HCMapFragmentActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.105: W/dalvikvm(1760): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity; (678)
07-11 23:40:04.105: W/dalvikvm(1760): Link of class 'Lcom/example/healthcity/activities/GroupLessonsActivity;' failed
07-11 23:40:04.118: I/dalvikvm(1760): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0f56 at 0x63 in Lcom/example/healthcity/networking/Networking;.doInBackground
07-11 23:40:04.205: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 144K, 10% free 2464K/2732K, paused 35ms, total 36ms
07-11 23:40:04.225: I/dalvikvm-heap(1760): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.771MB for 2355216-byte allocation
07-11 23:40:04.385: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 4764K/5036K, paused 157ms, total 157ms
07-11 23:40:04.435: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 4763K/5036K, paused 8ms+4ms, total 56ms
07-11 23:40:04.475: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 4763K/5036K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
07-11 23:40:04.486: I/dalvikvm-heap(1760): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.033MB for 1324816-byte allocation
07-11 23:40:04.655: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 6057K/6332K, paused 126ms+4ms, total 173ms
07-11 23:40:04.705: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2300K, 41% free 3759K/6332K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
07-11 23:40:04.725: I/dalvikvm-heap(1760): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.132MB for 2457616-byte allocation
07-11 23:40:04.916: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 30% free 6159K/8736K, paused 117ms+16ms, total 188ms
07-11 23:40:05.246: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 30% free 6159K/8736K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
07-11 23:40:05.246: I/dalvikvm-heap(1760): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.451MB for 1382416-byte allocation
07-11 23:40:05.346: D/dalvikvm(1760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 15% free 7509K/8736K, paused 22ms+5ms, total 94ms
07-11 23:40:05.436: E/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find class 'org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister', referenced from method com.silverputty.common.Tools.grabXML_YoutubeFeed
07-11 23:40:05.436: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1375 (Lorg/simpleframework/xml/core/Persister;) in Lcom/silverputty/common/Tools;
07-11 23:40:05.436: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0005
07-11 23:40:05.446: D/dalvikvm(1760): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x268e at 0x07 in Lcom/silverputty/common/Tools;.grabXML_YoutubeFeed
07-11 23:40:05.686: D/gralloc_goldfish(1760): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-11 23:40:06.796: I/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find method com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.onPageView, referenced from method com.silverputty.view.SilverActivity.onStart
07-11 23:40:06.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7635: Lcom/flurry/android/FlurryAgent;.onPageView ()V
07-11 23:40:06.826: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000c
07-11 23:40:06.826: I/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find method com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.onStartSession, referenced from method com.silverputty.view.SilverActivity.onStart
07-11 23:40:06.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7636: Lcom/flurry/android/FlurryAgent;.onStartSession (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V
07-11 23:40:06.826: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0023
07-11 23:40:06.826: I/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find method com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.onStartSession, referenced from method com.silverputty.view.SilverActivity.onStart
07-11 23:40:06.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7636: Lcom/flurry/android/FlurryAgent;.onStartSession (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V
07-11 23:40:06.826: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x002b
07-11 23:40:06.826: I/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find method com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.endTimedEvent, referenced from method com.silverputty.view.SilverActivity.onStop
07-11 23:40:06.826: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7632: Lcom/flurry/android/FlurryAgent;.endTimedEvent (Ljava/lang/String;)V
07-11 23:40:06.843: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000f
07-11 23:40:08.486: I/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.<init>
07-11 23:40:08.486: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve static method 676: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
07-11 23:40:08.496: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0019
07-11 23:40:08.516: I/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver, referenced from method com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onPause
07-11 23:40:08.526: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 679: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.unregisterReceiver (Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;)V
07-11 23:40:08.526: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
07-11 23:40:08.556: I/dalvikvm(1760): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver, referenced from method com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onResume
07-11 23:40:08.576: W/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 677: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.registerReceiver (Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;Landroid/content/IntentFilter;)V
07-11 23:40:08.576: D/dalvikvm(1760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0032
07-11 23:40:08.586: D/AndroidRuntime(1760): Shutting down VM
07-11 23:40:08.598: W/dalvikvm(1760): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.<init>(UiLifecycleHelper.java:58)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at com.example.healthcity.common.FacebookContainer.<init>(FacebookContainer.java:78)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at com.example.healthcity.activities.LoginActivity.onCreateX(LoginActivity.java:129)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at com.silverputty.view.SilverActivity.onCreate(SilverActivity.java:430)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-11 23:40:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 23:40:16.285: I/Process(1760): Sending signal. PID: 1760 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you have the proper resources / jar files added to your project?  Should be either in the assets folder or the libs folder

Comment: Your problem is the NoClassDefFoundError. Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16595708/2045570

Comment: @user2045570 you should add that as an answer so he can give you your points, if that's the solution.

Comment: @dispake yes i have added all the jars. and references in properties.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse I solved similar problem by checking the .jar I had already added in Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Order and Export (tab). After Project>Clean it worked fine.