# android : calling class from onResume()

Tags: android, calling-convention

I am trying to call a class from onResume() of my activity. But evrytime i am getting class not found error.

Here is the code for the onResume():

```java
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
      try {   
          sendHiddenMail sender = new sendHiddenMail("sidh*****@gmail.com", "pass");
          sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                  "This is Body",   
                  "sid*****@gmail.com",   
                  "sid*****@gmail.com");   
      } catch (Exception e) {   
          Log.e("SendMailsdfsdfsd", e.getMessage(), e);   
      }

 }
```

Here is the class whom I want to call:

```java
public class sendHiddenMail extends javax.mail.Authenticator{

private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
}  


 public sendHiddenMail(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
06-03 03:22:57.331: W/dalvikvm(4934): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/calllist/sendHiddenMail; (67)
06-03 03:22:57.331: W/dalvikvm(4934): Link of class 'Lcom/example/calllist/sendHiddenMail;' failed
06-03 03:22:57.331: E/dalvikvm(4934): Could not find class 'com.example.calllist.sendHiddenMail', referenced from method com.example.calllist.MainActivity.sendMail
06-03 03:22:57.331: W/dalvikvm(4934): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 34 (Lcom/example/calllist/sendHiddenMail;) in Lcom/example/calllist/MainActivity;
06-03 03:22:57.331: D/dalvikvm(4934): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
06-03 03:22:57.341: W/dalvikvm(4934): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/calllist/sendHiddenMail; (67)
06-03 03:22:57.341: W/dalvikvm(4934): Link of class 'Lcom/example/calllist/sendHiddenMail;' failed
06-03 03:22:57.401: D/dalvikvm(4934): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0039 at 0x06 in Lcom/example/calllist/MainActivity;.sendMail
06-03 03:22:57.791: D/AndroidRuntime(4934): Shutting down VM
06-03 03:22:57.791: W/dalvikvm(4934): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1af6b90)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934): Process: com.example.calllist, PID: 4934
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.calllist.sendHiddenMail
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.example.calllist.MainActivity.sendMail(MainActivity.java:102)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.example.calllist.MainActivity.getCallDetails(MainActivity.java:81)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.example.calllist.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:35)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5322)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2798)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
06-03 03:22:57.811: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 03:27:58.391: I/Process(4934): Sending signal. PID: 4934 SIG: 9
```

I have not added any information about sendHiddenMail class in mainfest.xml

I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: i hav eposted the logcat

Comment: It's pretty basic, but have you imported the class (assuming there's a need to). Also, what's the structure of your packages?

Comment: That superclass `javax.mail.Authenticator` is imported? By the way, you should use class names beginning with an upper case letter.

Comment: Off-topic : you should name your classes in TitleCase.

Comment: No javax.mail.Authenticator  was not imported. But i have tried it after importing it. No change . Still throws the same error.

Will keep in mind the naming conventions.

The activity class and sendHiddenMail class are in the same package.

Comment: I thing i found the error : **extends javax.mail.Authenticator**  is  causing the issue. I tried running without it , the code runs smoothly. But in real case i need to extend. Can any one have idea how to work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have imported `javax.mail.Authenticator` correctly, get no error at "compile" time and the app crashes at runtime, the solution might be [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589821/android-app-crashes-after-sdk-tools-update-version-noclassdeffound-tool-versio).
Yes, if you remove the class relationship, your code may work but it doesn't solve your problem. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Have tried cleaning the project and re bulding it. Nothing works.