# ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, docx4j

I am Using `docx4j` to read Docx file from sd card. I have problem with `org.apache.log4j.Logger` library. I have even tried to add it externally. but it is still giving me same problem.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shvet.pdfreaders"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
//    compile('org.docx4j:docx4j:2.8.0') {
//        transitive = false
//    }
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5'
    compile files('libs/docx4j-2.8.0.jar')
}
```

**Logcat**

> 02-16 16:15:48.025 24912-24912/com.shvet.pdfreaders E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.shvet.pdfreaders, PID: 24912
>                                                                         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;
>                                                                             at org.docx4j.openpackaging.Base.(Base.java:42)
>                                                                             at
>   com.shvet.pdfreaders.fragments.PdfViewFragment$6.fileSelected(PdfViewFragment.java:205)
>                                                                             at
>   com.shvet.pdfreaders.extra.FileChooser$1.onItemClick(FileChooser.java:59)
>                                                                             at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
>                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
>                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
>                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "org.apache.log4j.Logger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.shvet.pdfreaders-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                             at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                             at org.docx4j.openpackaging.Base.(Base.java:42) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.shvet.pdfreaders.fragments.PdfViewFragment$6.fileSelected(PdfViewFragment.java:205) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.shvet.pdfreaders.extra.FileChooser$1.onItemClick(FileChooser.java:59) 
>                                                                             at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305) 
>                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146) 
>                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057) 
>                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
>                                                                             Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
>                                                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                     ... 16 more
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack available

What I have done till now: I tried with jar file and external `log4j` and used gradle url with and without `log4j` library.

Comment: Check the classpath and JAR is placed under exact location.

Comment: problem occurs in both with jar file and with gradle url. So i dont think it is problem of classpath.

Comment: Could you please check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602640/noclassdeffounderror-android-project) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602640/noclassdeffounderror-android-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602640/noclassdeffounderror-android-project) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589821/android-app-crashes-after-sdk-tools-update-version-noclassdeffound-tool-versio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589821/android-app-crashes-after-sdk-tools-updat

Comment: @ManKeer two of above links are dead and working one do not have any answer related to android studio either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602640/noclassdeffounderror-android-project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641739/android-error-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-ut

Comment: @ManKeer are you new to Android studio? this solution is for eclipse only.