# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Onesignal and Android support V4

Tags: android, eclipse, onesignal

I just implemented oneSignal in my project to send push notifications.
Notifications are sent correctly when the application is launched but when I put in background I got this error : 
[image]

Im working with Eclipse and I know that is really recommended to migrate to Android Studio since Eclipse is not supported any more. The problem is that my client’s project is too old and I couldn’t perform the migration properly.

I think that the problem is caused by Android Support V4 but I don’t know how to fix. After googling and trying many solutions I still got the same issue.

I am an Android Developer beginner, any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: for good approach switch to android studio

Answer (score 1):

The Android Support Library you're using in your app is too old or is missing. Please use the latest version android support library v4 with your app.

Here is a StackOverflow answer that explains how to add this library: [Android app crashes after SDK-tools update version (NoClassDefFound, tool version 22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589821/android-app-crashes-after-sdk-tools-update-version-noclassdeffound-tool-versio)